# What is the purpose of '_' in macro

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to understand one of the VPP [sample](https://docs.fd.io/vpp/17.07/da/d30/sample_8c_source.html) function name 'sample_plugin_api_hookup'. What is the purpose of underscore ('_' ) in macro (`#define _(N,n)` ) ?

```
   #define _(N,n)                                                  \
        vl_msg_api_set_handlers((VL_API_##N + sm->msg_id_base),     \
                               #n,          \
                               vl_api_##n##_t_handler,              \
                               vl_noop_handler,                     \
                               vl_api_##n##_t_endian,               \
                               vl_api_##n##_t_print,                \
                               sizeof(vl_api_##n##_t), 1);
        foreach_sample_plugin_api_msg;
    #undef _
```

Comment: It is the name of the macro. Identifiers can start with underscore.

Comment: Thank you, Do you know how it is called?

Comment: It is called horrible, if the underscore is all there is to the name. Leading underscore names are reserved anyway.

Comment: @Tectrendz  It is called like _( N, n ) where N and n are some values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_` is a valid C identifier, though it's reserved for use at file scope. A C identifier consists of a letter or underscore, followed by zero or more letters, underscores, or digits (I'm ignoring universal character names).

Apparently the author of that code wanted a name that's short, easy to type, and unobtrusive. I believe the GNU gettext package, or code that uses it, follows this convention, with a macro call like

```
 _("This is a message")
```

being replaced by a localized version of the message. (Which means that a program that uses GNU gettext likely would have to pick a different name).

`foreach_sample_plugin_api_msg` is another macro that makes use of the `_` macro, which is why the `_` macro is undefined immediately after that line.

Perhaps the author was influenced by the Go language, which uses `_` as a *blank identifier*.

Opinions are likely to differ on the question of whether this is a neat trick or a crime against good taste.

Comment: Thank you, Keith !! I am still wondering how is it used within a function where it is defined and undef.

Comment: @Tectrendz: The `foreach_sample_plugin_api_msg` macro invokes the `_()` macro.

Comment: Thank you !! what are N and n?

Comment: Now I get it they are "SAMPLE_MACSWAP_ENABLE_DISABLE, sample_macswap_enable_disable"

Comment: *Opinions are likely to differ on the question of whether this is a neat trick or a crime against good taste.* I'm of the opinion that "neat tricks" are a crime against readable, maintainable code.  If you want to really show off how good you are, write some code that has others saying, "Wow, that's so simple and clear!"  Brilliant code doesn't cause a lot of thought and a "What in the world is going on here?!?!" response, it causes a, "Well dang, that's simple. Why didn't I think of that!!?!" reaction.

Comment: This looks like X macro usage (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).  I agree the "_" is a poor name, as is "X".  I prefer to pass the name of the macro into the list macro, and have been complimented on occasion with "dang that's simple" :)